# drawMarker() in cv2.aruco not found

Tags: python, computer-vision, aruco

I'm trying to use the function drawMarker() from OpenCV documentation in ArucoMarkers and for some reason it keeps giving me an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.aruco' has no attribute 'drawMarker'
```

If it helps, I am using VS code and coding in Python. I'm not sure why I don't have "drawMarker()" in my library.

I'm trying to print aruco markers in a matplotlib plot. This is my code for that.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a predefined dictionary object for ArUco markers
dictionary = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_250)

# Generate an ArUco marker image
marker_id = 23
marker_size = 200
# No need to pass an image to fill
marker_image = cv2.aruco.drawMarker(dictionary, marker_id, marker_size)

# Display the marker using matplotlib
plt.imshow(marker_image, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

This is my version (which I tried to make it as up to date as possible):

```
/Users/[OMITTED]/Desktop/test/aruco_markers.py 4.8.1
```

When I ran print(dir(cv2.aruco)):

```
rtcbhiv01a02:python_gui [OMITTED]$ /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/[OMITTED]/Desktop/test/aruco_markers.py
['ARUCO_CCW_CENTER', 'ARUCO_CW_TOP_LEFT_CORNER', 'ArucoDetector', 'Board', 'CORNER_REFINE_APRILTAG', 'CORNER_REFINE_CONTOUR', 'CORNER_REFINE_NONE', 'CORNER_REFINE_SUBPIX', 'CharucoBoard', 'CharucoDetector', 'CharucoParameters', 'DICT_4X4_100', 'DICT_4X4_1000', 'DICT_4X4_250', 'DICT_4X4_50', 'DICT_5X5_100', 'DICT_5X5_1000', 'DICT_5X5_250', 'DICT_5X5_50', 'DICT_6X6_100', 'DICT_6X6_1000', 'DICT_6X6_250', 'DICT_6X6_50', 'DICT_7X7_100', 'DICT_7X7_1000', 'DICT_7X7_250', 'DICT_7X7_50', 'DICT_APRILTAG_16H5', 'DICT_APRILTAG_16h5', 'DICT_APRILTAG_25H9', 'DICT_APRILTAG_25h9', 'DICT_APRILTAG_36H10', 'DICT_APRILTAG_36H11', 'DICT_APRILTAG_36h10', 'DICT_APRILTAG_36h11', 'DICT_ARUCO_MIP_36H12', 'DICT_ARUCO_MIP_36h12', 'DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL', 'DetectorParameters', 'Dictionary', 'Dictionary_getBitsFromByteList', 'Dictionary_getByteListFromBits', 'EstimateParameters', 'GridBoard', 'RefineParameters', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_native', 'calibrateCameraAruco', 'calibrateCameraArucoExtended', 'calibrateCameraCharuco', 'calibrateCameraCharucoExtended', 'detectCharucoDiamond', 'detectMarkers', 'drawCharucoDiamond', 'drawDetectedCornersCharuco', 'drawDetectedDiamonds', 'drawDetectedMarkers', 'drawPlanarBoard', 'estimatePoseBoard', 'estimatePoseCharucoBoard', 'estimatePoseSingleMarkers', 'extendDictionary', 'generateImageMarker', 'getBoardObjectAndImagePoints', 'getPredefinedDictionary', 'interpolateCornersCharuco', 'refineDetectedMarkers', 'testCharucoCornersCollinear']
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `marker_image = cv2.aruco.generateImageMarker(dictionary, marker_id, marker_size)`?

Comment: API changed sometime after v4.5.5. some of the code has now been scattered across "the aruco module" and also the "objdetect" module. that makes finding APIs a bit tricky. search function in the docs will find them though, if you know what to ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OpenCV 4.7.0` brought few changes in API. `generateImageMarker()` should be used instead of `drawMarker()`.

Original c++ [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html) was updated with:

```cpp
cv::Mat markerImage;
cv::aruco::Dictionary dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_6X6_250);
cv::aruco::generateImageMarker(dictionary, 23, 200, markerImage, 1);
cv::imwrite("marker23.png", markerImage);
```

Corresponding working solution in python:

```py
import cv2

dictionary = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
marker_id = 23
marker_size = 200
marker_image = cv2.aruco.generateImageMarker(dictionary, marker_id, marker_size)
```

Printing will bring you the desired marker:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(marker_image, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: AcUro #23]

Comment: thanks a lot, i really appreciate it!!